# Hanging Plastic Pan Formed Sign on Concrete Wall

Tags: concrete, hanging, plastic

I need to hang a plastic, pan formed business sign on an interior concrete wall. It's embossed and has flat flanges on the sides, weighs around 40lbs. It's similar to this: https://www.signcrafters-inc.com/uploaded_files/images/Ziebart_Sign.jpg

I want something that's easy to install and remove multiple times (rules out tapcons).

I was thinking of mounting two 2x4s to the concrete wall with tapcons then screwing the sign to the wood. I would ideally want something not visible from the outside.

Is there a way to attach 50lb picture wire to the back securely? Literally any idea would be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Inside or outside?  Outside need to be aware of wind, so mounting must be different.

Comment: Technically off topic. More importantly to me, the linked picture is useless for determining if the "flat flanges" are 90 degrees to the wall or 0 degrees (parallel) to the wall. If parallel to the wall, simple to make a wood (or metal) frame with a slot that they can be slid into, with no fasteners needed (other than those holding the frame to the wall) for an interior application

Comment: Image link is not valid

Comment: While technically about a commercial installation, I think that if it were [edit]ed to simply be "I need to hang this plastic thing on a concrete wall", it would be perfectly fine. Of course, it would need a picture of the _ACTUAL_ plastic thing, not some pic randomly found on the internet that's "just like it" but turns out to be totally different...

Comment: Only way to do something not visible from the front is to *glue* something to the back and attach that to the wall.  Like a french cleat.  Or several giant magnets.  If you can live with minimal "visible" you could fasten a number of wall mirror brackets to the wall.

Answer (score 2):

Concrete anchors (RedHed™ is an example) or anchor screws (Tapcon™ is a popular brand) seem to be the best idea. However, you indicate that this needs to be removed regularly.

For *anything* that needs to be screwed in then removed regularly, *threaded inserts* are definitely the way to go.

A simple internet search for `concrete threaded insert` returned quite a number of options. [This link](https://www.mcmaster.com/concrete-inserts/) to McMaster-Carr®'s page for concrete threaded inserts happened to be the first result in the list and is a well known nation-wide retailer. I have no affiliation with them and don't even think I've ever actually purchased anything from them, though I've definitely heard of them. There were also what appeared to be quite a number of local companies that sell them, as well.

I believe that the installation of as many anchors as you feel necessary (based on the weight of the thing being installed and the ratings of the anchors) and some simple machine screws/bolts with matching threads would, in all likelihood, be your simplest answer.

If you have a poured concrete wall, you can put them anywhere you want. If you have a block wall, I'd suggest spacing them so they go into the webs of the blocks and don't end up with the interior end hanging into the void in a block.